# Objective C process pool management

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parallel-processing, cocoapods

I'm looking for a process pool management library, maybe with an interface similar to Python's `concurrent.futures`.

My goal is to **open N processes to execute a task, and when one finishes, create a new one in its stead**. So at any single point in time, there are N running processes.

Is there something in existence?

Comment: Have you considered grand central dispatch's (GCD) concurrent queues?

Comment: I thought they use threads, not processes. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Apologies, yes GCD uses threads so if you need OS level processes then its not your solution. No answers yet so maybe it will be roll-your-own with `NSTask` and `terminationHandler` (and maybe using a GCD serial queue to process those terminations).

Comment: @Dor, why do you need processes vs. threads?

Comment: I need to use an external program to encode media files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my own class.
I hope it can be of use to someone: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/dorfire/8jdLn